# How to disable F5 and Refresh in Firefox browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

```
<Script language="javascript">
function checkKeyCode(evt)
{

var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
if(event.keyCode==116)
{
evt.keyCode=0;
return false
}
}
document.onkeydown=checkKeyCode;
</script>
```

I tried this it is working fine in IE but it doesn't work in Firefox.................please help me.

Comment: You cant force anything on Users browser

Comment: WHY?! Refreshing is a fundamental function of a browser. Work *with* it, not against it. Also hint: F5 is only the Windows convention for "refresh". There are many more platforms out there and there's always a toolbar button that does the same.

Comment: Hai guys, actually my problem is whenever I refresh the form it is submitted again and it is throwing the exception, that's way I want to disable the refresh in my application.

Comment: this is not the way to fix your problem. on submission of the form, make immediately a redirect to another page, thus refreshing the target page won't cause you problems anymore. Another solution is to ignore repeated submissions.

Comment: Twitter web site disables F5

Answer (score 4):

Classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're asking for a solution to a problem to a non-solution to a problem that needs to be solved in a completely different way.

The correct pattern is called POST-redirect-GET. After each POST request (a form submit) you **redirect** the user to a different or even the same page, which causes a regular GET request. When the user then refreshes the page, a regular GET request will be issued without resubmitting the form.

See [Trying to understand the Post/Redirect/Get design pattern (implemented with PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882149/trying-to-understand-the-post-redirect-get-design-pattern-implemented-with-php) and similar questions for more details.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode==116){
    return false;
   }
}
```