# Every time i refresh page it inserts same user into database

Tags: php, mysql

Here is PHP code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Murad'])){
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
$userName=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['pwd1'];
$userName = stripslashes($userName);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$email=$_POST['email'];
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "123";
$mysql_databse = "websiteusers";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
$sql = "INSERT INTO websiteusers 
       (fullname,lastname,userName,email,pass) 
       VALUES ( '$firstname', '$lastname','$userName', '$email','$password')";
        mysqli_select_db($bd,'websiteusers');
$retval = mysqli_query($bd,$sql );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ');
  return false;
}
else {echo "Entered data successfully\n";
   }

   $usernamecheck=mysqli_query($bd,"SELECT `userName` FROM `websiteusers` 
                             WHERE userName='$userName'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($usernamecheck)>=1){
   echo $userName." is already taken";
 return false;
 }header("Location: Main.php");}

?>
```

User registers then when he is in his profile page as soon as he refreshes it inserts same username again.And also username and email are unique in my dt it cant insert it and gives an error

Comment: you may want to look at the POST/Redirect/GET pattern, ie. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882149/trying-to-understand-the-post-redirect-get-design-pattern-implemented-with-php or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing right now is you insert a user in the DB and after that you perform a check if the user exists. You'll have to move some code around.

```
$bd = mysqli_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
 $usernamecheck=mysqli_query($bd,"SELECT `userName` FROM `websiteusers` 
                             WHERE userName='$userName'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($usernamecheck)>=1){
   echo $userName." is already taken";
 } else {
$sql = "INSERT INTO websiteusers 
       (fullname,lastname,userName,email,pass) 
       VALUES ( '$firstname', '$lastname','$userName', '$email','$password')";
        mysqli_select_db($bd,'websiteusers');
$retval = mysqli_query($bd,$sql );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ');
}
else {
    echo "Entered data successfully\n";
}
}
    }
```

This way you first check if the user already exists. If does - you kill the script and the code after is not executed. Otherwise you insert a user in the DB

Comment: it gives error in this line "if(mysqli_num_rows($usernamecheck)>=1)"

Comment: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\AppServ\www\murad\centil\o\ch.php on line 18

Comment: Try changing the SELECT query to `SELECT * FROM websiteusers 
                             WHERE userName='$userName'"`

Comment: I added this code  $result=mysqli_query($bd,$usernamecheck) or die();
and it deleted that error but now it gives mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Empty query in

Comment: Basically that error means that the query failed. Usually this is a syntax error (which doesn't seem to be the case) or the table\column don't exist.

Comment: But im sure there is column like that

Comment: change the if to `if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>=1){`

Comment: do an `echo mysqli_error($bd);` before the `if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>=1)` and see the result

Comment: Okay it deleted that error(i forgot to select dt) but guess what? new error

Comment: You should stop saying that without specifying the error

Comment: I commented that in answer above but here it is  mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in

Comment: Change the query back to `$usernamecheck=mysqli_query($bd,"SELECT * FROM websiteusers
                             WHERE userName='$userName'");`

Comment: it always was like that.Error is about  $result=mysqli_query($bd,$usernamecheck) or die();

Comment: Where did you put that line?

Comment: remove that line, change the if back to `if(mysqli_num_rows($usernamecheck)>=1)`

Comment: now it removed all errors but it adds username again

Comment: instead of `echo $userName." is already taken";` do `die($userName." is already taken");`

Comment: There you go. Code works as expected. If you don't want the code to exit you have to play with your if - else statements, otherwise your problem should be solved

Comment: Same errors                                                                                   mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given                         mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given        mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in               mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in

Comment: Change the part before if to what you had when it didn't throw any errors

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is after the form has submitted successfully,

> you can reset the form

or

> redirect the user to the same page

```
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ');
  return false;
}
else {
    echo "Entered data successfully\n";
     header("Location:samepagename.php");

   }
```

TO reset the form

```
      this.form.reset();
```

call this after form has successfully submitted

Comment: $('#full').submit(function(e){
    
     this. FORM.reset(); 
    
    console.log("submitted"); 
});

Comment: yes but call it inside php after the form has submitted and value have been inserted like this `echo '<script> $('#full').submit(function(e){ this. FORM.reset(); console.log("submitted"); }); </script>'`

Comment: but this is not usually a good practice, because in the current scenario your  form and the submit code is on the same page, so this can work but not when you are following some good standards for development like MVC then you only have one option is to redirect the user

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Murad'])) {
        $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
        $userName=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['pwd1'];
        $userName = stripslashes($userName);
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
        $mysql_user = "root";
        $mysql_password = "123";
        $mysql_databse = "websiteusers";
        $prefix = "";

        $link = new PDO('mysql:dbhost='.$mysql_hostname.';dbname='.$mysql_database,$mysql_user, $mysql_password);
        $unamecheck = ("SELECT userName FROM websiteusers WHERE userName = :uname");
        $unamecheck = $link->prepare($unamecheck);
        $unamecheck->execute(array(':uname'=>$userName));
        if($unamecheck->rowCount() > 0) {
            echo "Username taken";
            die();
        } else {
            $add = ("INSERT INTO websiteusers (fullname, lastname, userName, email, pass) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :uname, :pass)");
            $add = $link->prepare($add);
            $add->execute(array(':fname'=>$firstname, ':lname'=>$lastname, ':uname'=>$userName, ':pass'=>$password));
            if($add->rowCount() > 0) {
                echo "Registration successful";
                header("Location: Main.php");
            } else {
                echo "Registration failed";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in

Comment: it showed bunch of errors                                                                          :Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\AppServ\www\murad\centil\o\ch.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\AppServ\www\murad\centil\o\ch.php(16): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbhost=lo...', 'root', '123') #1 C:\AppServ\www\murad\centil\o\Main.php(2): include('C:\AppServ\www\...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\AppServ\www\murad\centil\o\ch.php on line 16